# Resetting database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-postgres

Now I am trying to reset database on heroku but got stuck.

I know I should do "heroku pg:reset Database URL but I don't know exactly what the databese url is.

I did "heroku config". So I got some strings. And tried

```
heroku pg:reset postgres://ffsqtmlnxntfvl:ajqGTMGEmT7U1S6sVdi7-bb7Cm@ec2-107-20-245-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dc2kahsue8hn20. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL
```

My command,however,always returns this to me.

Unknown database: postgres://xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.xxxxxxx.com:xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL

What should I do? Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I just put "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA" itself and then made it!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but as I've just been through this, here is what I did:

1. heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_HEROKUCOLOR_URL --confirm {app_name}
2. heroku run rake db:schema:load
3. heroku run rake db:migrate
4. heroku run rake db:seed

As per: [Heroku rake db:migrate does not create tables (Rails 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106064/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-does-not-create-tables-rails-5)